# How do you insert a tab character in Kate?

Tags: kate

<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys are for indenting and unindenting in the "Normal" indentation mode, which is the default. These are fine and do exactly what I want.

[image]

Occasionally it is useful to insert a literal tab character into the document, but I can't figure out how to do it without changing the options each time. Pasting a tab naturally transforms it into four spaces as configured.

I'm using Kate 3.14.9.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works (long time since I used Kate).

Activate VI input mode, Ctrl-V, Tab, Exit VI mode.
Ctrl-V in VI takes the next key typed (Tab in this case) and insert it literally without interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

**Kate has a function specifically for this!**
There just isn’t any shortcut assigned to it by default.

Go to `Settings` → `Configure Keyboard Shortcuts (Ctrl-Alt-,)`, then enter `insert` into the search. You will find a shortcut named `Insert Tab`. Assign a shortcut to it, and you’re done.

**By the way,** to avoid having to switch to VI mode via the menus, if you want to enter another literal character, you can use `Ctrl-Alt-V`, to  `Switch to next Input Mode`.

Finally, Kate as a command line, that allows inserting even more complex things. So if you need it, you can look up how to do that too. :)